# fileupload path is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net

hai friends

I am using a file  upload control to upload the files if the user browse and upload the file. after uploading the path gets disappears. i should be maintain there itself. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is the default behavior of the browsers for security reasons

have a look at MS support site for IE http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266087

**Edit**

In your code behind you can try something like

```
fileUpload.Attributes.Add('value',filename);
```

see if this works.